# "Je ne reviendrai pas d'aujourd'hui" : pourquoi d'aujourd'hui ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

J'ai entendu quelqu'un dire :

> Je ne reviendrai pas **d'aujourd'hui**. (pas le pléonasme Au jour d'aujourd'hui).

Que signifie ce **d(e)** ici ? Est-ce d'un registre familier ? Quelle est la différence avec

> Je ne reviendrai pas aujourd'hui.

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Je ne trouve personnellement rien de familier dans la présence de la préposition *de* devant *aujourd'hui*.  C'est le même emploi que dans :

- Je ne reviendrai pas **de** la journée.

Note que le *de* ne peut se mettre (optionnel) qu'à la forme négative et que tu ne peux pas dire la même chose à la forme affirmative.

[*Larousse* en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aujourd_hui/6459) :

> *D'aujourd'hui* ou plus couramment *aujourd'hui* se disent pour « toute la journée, de toute la journée » : *il ne viendra pas d'aujourd'hui* ou *aujourd'hui*.

[*Dictionnaire de l'Académie*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8D0089) :

> *De* entre aussi dans plusieurs locutions adverbiales, ou autres, qui indiquent une certaine époque ou une certaine durée. [...] *Il ne viendra pas d’aujourd’hui*.

*Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française* (Jean Girodet, 2010) :

> D'aujourd'hui. S'emploie très correctement pour dire « pendant la durée de la journée où nous sommes  » : *je ne l'ai pas vu d'aujourd'hui*.

Comment: Littré constitue une autre source (historique) car il dit « D'aujourd'hui, depuis le commencement de la journée » : _Je ne l'ai point encore embrassé d'aujourd'hui_ (Racine).

Answer (score 1):

Exemples tirés par Littré (version en ligne) :

> D'aujourd'hui, à partir du moment où nous sommes.
>
> Ce n'est pas d'aujourd'hui que tu sais allier La vertu, les forfaits, l'amant, le meurtrier, Voltaire, Catil. II, 2.
>
> D'aujourd'hui je commence à sentir tout le poids de ma triste puissance, Voltaire, Orphel. IV, 1.
>
> D'aujourd'hui seulement je jouis de ma gloire, Racine, Andr. II, 5.
>
> Où mon Abel est-il ? parle, est-ce d'aujourd'hui Que nous craignons Caïn ? que tu connais sa haine ? Gilbert, Mort d'Abel, ch. VIII.
>
> Ce n'est pas d'aujourd'hui que l'opinion gouverne le monde, Guez de Balzac, liv. VI, lett. 1.
>
> D'aujourd'hui en huit, en quinze, expression elliptique signifiant dans huit jours, dans quinze jours à compter d'aujourd'hui.

https://www.littre.org/definition/aujourd%27hui

Peut-être dans un contexte particulier je ne reviendrai pas d'aujourd'hui signifie je ne reviendrai pas à partir du moment où nous sommes.

Comment: Pour dire « du moment où nous sommes » (qui n'est pas idiomatique mais compréhensible) je ne connais pas d'autre façon courante que « à partir d'aujourd'hui » et « à partir de maintenant ».

Answer (score -7):

« D'aujourd'hui » pour signifier « de toute la journée » ne se dit pas [[ngram]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reviendrai%20pas%20d%27aujourd%27hui%2Creviendrai%20pas%20aujourd%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creviendrai%20pas%20aujourd%27hui%3B%2Cc0)), c'est à dire que c'est très rare, mais correct ; on trouvera ci-dessous une attestation du TLFi (1853).

[pas mangé d'aujourd'hui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+mang%C3%A9+d%27aujourd%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), 
[pas mangé de la journée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+mang%C3%A9+de+la+journ%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20mang%C3%A9%20de%20la%20journ%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)

[pas vu d'aujourd'hui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+vu+d%27aujourd%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), [pas vu de la journée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+vu+de+la+journ%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20vu%20de%20la%20journ%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)

[pas bougé d'aujourd'hui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+boug%C3%A9+d%27aujourd%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), [pas bougé de la journée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+boug%C3%A9+de+la+journ%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20boug%C3%A9%20de%20la%20journ%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpas%20boug%C3%A9%20de%20la%20journ%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)

On trouve la même chose pour les participes suivants : paru, cessé, quitté, sorti.

> a) D'aujourd'hui mis pour aujourd'hui. [De = quant à (avec une légère idée de durée)] De tout le jour :
>
> - Mais, Monsieur Bineau, vous êtes trop pressé... Vous me faites perdre la tête avec votre poëme. Est-il fini?
>     Oh! Je n'ai pas pu travailler d'aujourd'hui.
>     CHAMPFLEURY, Les Souffrances du professeur Delteil, 1853, p. 199.

Comment: @sinopleincandescent « Je n'ai pas mangé d'aujourd'hui. » ne se dit pas. Les ngrams sont là pour le prouver. Je n'ai jamais entendu ça de ma vie.

Comment: @Dimitris Qu'est-ce vous voyez de faux dans « voir ngram » ? Je voudrais bien comprendre.

Comment: @LPH Je m'excuse. Ma faute.

Comment: @Dimitris Ça va bien comme ça aussi, laissez le.

Comment: [Je ne suis pas sorti d'aujourd'hui](https://bit.ly/2oR1vHl) et je le dis. [Je ne l'ai pas vu d'aujourd'hui](https://bit.ly/35EAasu). [Je n'ai pas mangé d'aujourd'hui](https://bit.ly/2nPTj9F). Il y a tant de choses dans ce vaste monde que je n'ai jamais vues ou entendues, ça ne les empêche pas d'exister au-delà de mon humble personne.@sinopleincandescent

Comment: @Laure Comment cela se fait-il que dans la langue écrite les gens n'utilisent jamais cette forme et qu'ils utilisent toujours « de (toute) la journée » et comment se fait-il que je n'ai jamais entendu « d'aujourd'hui » ni ne l'ai jamais utilisé ? Le résultat des ngrams est le même pour tous les participes passé et ceux-là sont les plus courants. La raison est que ça ne se dit pas.

Comment: Je ne dois utiliser qu'une infime partie des choses qu'il est possible de dire. Si tout ce que je ne dis pas et n'ai jamais entendu ne se disait pas le monde serait bien pauvre et il me resterait bien peu de choses à découvrir et ce serait bien triste. L’outil Ngram repose sur la base de données textuelles de Google Livres, c'est à dire peu par rapport à ce qui existe. Par ailleurs l'outil n'a pas été mis à jour depuis plusieurs années et ses défauts ont été pointés. Mais j'ai pris en priorité des phrases trouvées dans Google Livres pour te montrer que l'outil n'est pas fiable.

Comment: @Laure Au contraire, je trouve encore une fois que Google est fiable et que la recherche correspond très souvent à ce que l'on pressent. Pourquoi user **jlliagre** l'utiliserait-il si souvent ?

Comment: Je crois que c'est votre certitude et l'air d'absolu qui expliquent le feedback négatif. "Ça ne se dit pas". Est-ce que vous avez fait des études linguistiques ? On vous a dit plusieurs fois que ni Ngram, ni TLFi ne sont panacée.

Comment: Parce que @jlliagre, lui, sait l'utiliser et sait vérifier les résultats. "Ngrams not found..." ne veut pas dire que ça n'existe pas, juste que Ngram ne trouve pas.

Comment: @Dimitris Je crois toujours que ça ne se dit pas ; est-ce que ces utilisateurs qui disent le contraire apportent des preuves ? Non, il n'ont pas la moindre preuve.

Comment: https://www.littre.org/definition/aujourd%27hui

Comment: @Laure En cherchant un peu plus j'ai trouvé quelque chose d'intéressant ; l'usage a quand même existé et comme il n'est pas considéré comme rare ou obsolète on devrait avoir des traces de nos jours. (voir la référence dans la correction (TLFi)).